# ZenFone AR and Lenovo Phab 2 Pro, which one is better for AR development?

Tags: augmented-reality, smartphone, google-project-tango

**Google** provides the **AR** developers with **Tango** platform.
There are two smart phones supporting Tango, **ZenFone AR** and **Lenovo Phab 2 Pro**.
If you are a AR developer then which one you gonna choose?

Comment: Since @ylac said they are not released yet, I will leave this question here until someone has the test report or maybe someday I will answer it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

One of them isn't even out yet (Q2 2017) and couldn't be tested by anyone since there were no Tango apps installed when they showed it at CES, so how should one compare? The hardware seems to be stronger, it will be smaller, but the price is still unknown.